# Tf Idf over a set of documents to find words relevance

Tags: java, python, tf-idf, words, tfidfvectorizer

I have 2 books in txt format (6000+ lines). I would like to associate, using Python,  to each word its relevance (using td idf algorithm) and order them in descending order.
I tried this code

```
#- * -coding: utf - 8 - * -
    from __future__
import division, unicode_literals
import math
from textblob
import TextBlob as tb

def tf(word, blob):
    return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return sum(1
        for blob in bloblist
        if word in blob)

def idf(word, bloblist):
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
    return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)

document1 = tb(""
    "FULL BOOK1 TEST"
    "")
document2 = tb(""
    "FULL BOOK2 TEST"
    "")



bloblist = [document1, document2]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    with open("result.txt", 'w') as textfile:
    print("Top words in document {}".format(i + 1))
scores = {
    word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words
}
sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
for word, score in sorted_words:
    textfile.write("Word: {}, TF-IDF: {}".format(word, round(score, 5)) + "\n")
```

that I found here https://stevenloria.com/tf-idf/ with some changes, but it takes a lot of time and after some minutes, it crashes saying `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found`.
Why?

I also tried to call this Java program through python https://github.com/mccurdyc/tf-idf/. The program works, but the output is incorrect: there are a lot of words that should have a high relevance level that are instead categorized with 0 relevance.

Is there a way to fix that Python code?
Or, can you suggest me another tf-idf implementation that does correctly what I want?